# Algebra: How many guests are there if you have a faint idea of the number of dishes and meat?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question intrigued me because this sounds like a trick question. It goes like this:

"A Chinese writer Sun Tsu Pao put these words into a mount of a woman washing the dishes in the river. "I don't know how many guests there were but every two used a dish for rice between them, every three a dish for meat and there were 65 dishes in all". How many guests were there?"

How do you answer the question above?

Comment: They could've worded it better, but the point of such questions is as far from failing students as can be.

Comment: I don't think this is a trick question.

Comment: I think that what you have trouble with here is not actually mathematics, but language. It seems that you can't decode the text and understand what it is saying.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't understand the logic behind this question, but it is insulting to math educators to suggest that we give "trick questions" to "fail pupils". If you want help understanding this, ask for help politely, don't just claim that it must be some sort of malicious trick just because you don't get it. That's on you, not math educators.

Comment: @Sean English I'm sorry. I will ask properly next time:-) I'm editing it properly......

Comment: @PalautotKa Thanks for the edit. The question sounds much more reasonable now.

Comment: should be "put these words into the mouth of"   For real people in a conversation, it means paraphrasing or incorrectly reporting what someone else said. For a writer and a fictional character, it just means writing what the character said.   Apparently from this: https://www.scribd.com/document/273234178/review-A   36 b.A Chinese writer Sun Tsu Pao put these words into the mouth of a woman washing dishes in the river.

Comment: @WillJagy woah......It came from that site? I peeked at it. Seems the questions were somewhat advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $g$ guests. Then there are $\frac{g}{2}$ rice plates and $\frac{g}{3}$ meat plates. Since there were a total of $65$ plates, then we can set up the equation
$$\frac{g}{2}+\frac{g}{3}=65$$
$$\frac{5}{6}g=65$$
$$g=78$$
and so there are $78$ guests.

Comment: Gee, thanks!    I'll try to understand why 78 is the answer....

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 78.
I already saw this question in a multiple choice examination but the choices are 50, 60, 70, 80
the equation for this is Guest/2 + Guest/3 = 65 and yo will come up with 78 as the answer, but wait there is no 78 in the choices.
so i just used a logical way to solve it.
my logical thinking is here, the guest will not just order a rice and eat it without a meat. hahaha! so for every 6 guest they will used 5 dishes (2 dishes for meat and 3 dishes for rice), 65 dishes / 5 dishes = 13
13 x 6 guest = 78 guest in all.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If there were six people, they would use three dishes of rice (there are three pairs of two people, and each pair is one dish between them), and two dishes of meat. In total, five dishes.

Comment: Hmmm...I'll use this hint......